# Solve equation with floor function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

can somebody help me with the following equation:

$$(1+x)^{ \left \lfloor{t}\right \rfloor}(1+x(t-  \left \lfloor{t}\right \rfloor)) = 2$$

I have to solve the equation to the variable $t$. First I've tried to use $\log$-function but then I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Have you tried running cases on this problem? Perhaps split up the fractional and integer parts of $t$ into $p+\{p\} $ and then you're flooring  operations will dissappear

Comment: If $t=n+\epsilon$ we have that $n=\frac{\log(2)-\log(1+x\epsilon}{\log(1+x)}$. This trivially gives the case when $t$ is an integer, but I'm not sure how to solve for $t$ itself

Comment: You are aware of how terrible this problem is,  correct? My guess is it doesn't have a nice solution. Just take a look at [the implicit plot from WA](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%7C+%281%2Bx%29%5E%28floor%28y%29%29+%281-x+%28y-floor%28y%29%29%29+%3D+2+%7C+x+%3D+0+to+10+y+%3D+0+to+10&x=0&y=0)...

Comment: Yeah it doesn't look like it has a nice solution...

Comment: The thing is the following:  I want to know, starting with a capital K(0), at whic h exact time does the start capital double up using mixed interest calculation, i.e. $K(t) = K(0)(1+i)^{\left \lfloor{t}\right \rfloor}(1+i(t- \left \lfloor{t}\right \rfloor))$...If I set $K(t)=2K(0)$ I end up with above equation...

Comment: If you split into cases you can determine the gist of the graph. You can bound the function above and below each interval [n, n+1] by a rectangle. The top of the rectangle is the value at $\epsilon\in (0,1)$ and the lower value can be found by means of differentiation I presume. I'll work out the specific here in a bit and post an answer. Using that info you can probably draw,  for each integer $n$, a line from the value at $\epsilon =0$ to the minimum and a line from the minimum to $\epsilon=1$. This should approximate the function fairly well within each interval

Comment: Even more so,  it might be possible to find a curve with better approximates the graph and yet remains easy to calculate.... I'll look into it. The approximations arent exact of course, but are nice for asymptotics and for getting a good numerical estimate.